# Negative lookahead on multiple strings

Tags: centos, grep, regular-expression

I need to find usages of [Short Open Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in PHP files, which mean matching `<?` but not `<?php`, `<?xml`, or `<?=`. In most regex flavours that would be something like this:

```
 <\?(?!php|xml|=)
```

However, the following line is matching the unwanted `<?php`, `<?xml`, and `<?=` portions:

```
$ grep -r -E "<\?(?\!php|=|xml)" *
```

I've tried scores of permutations of backslashes, `-P` and `-e` flags. **How does one properly use a negative lookahead in GNU grep?**

[CentOS 7.3](https://www.centos.org/) (KDE desktop), [GNU grep 2.20](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) (the online docs are for 3.0, but I've got `man` locally), [Nescafé Decaff](http://www.nestle.com/brands/allbrands/nescafe-decaff) (this might actually be the *real* problem).

Comment: just `grep -P '<\?(?!(php|=|xml))'` ?

Comment: Depends what exactly you mean by "flavor", but many (even most?!) people would say "most flavors" of regex do *not* support the Perl 5+ extensions of the regular expression formalism.

Comment: @iruvar Post as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need `-P` for PCRE which implements the Perl `(?!...)` negative lookahead, and to **not** escape the `!` in the `(?!...)`.

```
-bash-4.2$ cat input
<?php
<?xml
<?=
<?okay
<?
-bash-4.2$ grep -P '<\?(?!php|xml|=)' input
<?okay
<?
-bash-4.2$
```

`"<\?(?\!php|=|xml)"` is incorrect as this passes `(?\!...)` to `grep` and `?\!` is totally not `?!` as far as the regular expression engine is concerned; if you are unsure what is being passed through to a program by the shell either write some code to inspect that:

```
$ perl -E 'printf "%*vd\n","\t",$ARGV[0];say join "\t",split //,$ARGV[0]' "?\!"
63  92  33
?   \   !
$
```

Or use something like `strace` to see what `grep` got:

```
-bash-4.2$ strace -o grep grep "?\!grep" /etc/passwd
-bash-4.2$ grep grep grep
execve("/usr/bin/grep", ["grep", "?\\!grep", "/etc/passwd"], [/* 24 vars */]) = 0
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: Thank you! Why isn't `grep` affected by the difference between `'!'` and `"\!"`? Does `bash` not pass the same input to `grep` after interpreting the line?

Comment: Bash leaves backslashes which didn't do anything useful.

Comment: If only I could upvote twice! Thank you, the edit is very informative.

Comment: `grep grep grep` Somebody has been drinking too much beer!

Comment: Did you just write a ridiculously over-engineered `echo` in Perl?  *shudder*

Comment: @Kevin could be worse, could be *python*. Also since when does `echo` do `od(1)` type diagnostics?